# ios UIButton not loading url in UIWwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uibutton, nsurlrequest

I have made an iOS app to load a simple `UIWebView *mWeb`.

1. Once the app starts it loads my `originalURL`.
2. At the bottom of the UI, I have a `UIButton` placed `*btnHome`.
3. When I click this `UIButton` I want it load another URL `*loadNextURL`.

However something's not working on my end... HELP!

Here's the code for my `myViewController.h` file.

```
#import "myViewController.h"

@interface myViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnHome;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *mWeb;

@end

@implementation myViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *originalURL = @"http://myOriginalLink";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:originalURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_mWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (IBAction)btnHome:(id)sender
{
    NSString *loadNextURL = @"http://link2";
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:loadNextURL];
    NSURLRequest *reqObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    [_mWeb loadRequest:reqObj];
}

@end
```

Comment: did you link your button in your interface builder? In the method of button action put some NSLOG and check if you are pressing the button your log is showing

Comment: done...forgot to bound it...hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there can be two problems, first check that your action method is bound to the button or not. Second the url in stringVariable loadNextUrl is valid or not.

Now how to check the url is valid or not, just copy the url and paste into the browser. If the link does not open then the url is not valid. So for that pass the valid url in the string variable and then try.

Comment: If this ans really helps you then please mark it correct.So that it helps other as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Url it may be invalid. If it works fine in your browser then check your method. It may not be linked with your button with `touchUpInside` event. Then try using `[yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"yourLink"]];` . Also do check whether your web view is not nil. It won't be nil as you are able to load it in viewDidLoad. But do check it.